# How can I specify a list of allowable values in a LiquiBase constraint?

Tags: sql, constraints, liquibase

I have a table I am trying to create using liquibase.

In plain old SQL, I would write

```
CREATE TABLE foo_bar (
  foo_bar_id    varchar2(40)   NOT NULL,
  is_foo        number(1)      NOT NULL,
  is_bar        number(1)      NOT NULL,
  CHECK (is_foo IN (0, 1)),
  CHECK (is_bar IN (0, 1)),
  PRIMARY KEY(foo_bar_id)
);
```

What is the equivalent (of the `CHECK (is_foo IN (0, 1))` statement) in liquibase XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquibase currently does not support check constraints directly. You need to run a custom SQL to do that:

```
<createTable name="foo_bar">
  .... here is the table definition without the check constraint
</createTable>
<sql splitStatements="false">
  alter table foo_bar 
    add constraint check_is_foo CHECK (is_foo IN (0, 1))
</sql>
<sql splitStatements="false">
  alter table foo_bar 
    add constraint check_is_bar CHECK (is_bar IN (0, 1))
</sql>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Just an added note, CHECK constraint names need to be globally unique (within the schema)

Comment: @Vihung: not only check constraints, **all** constraint names.